# has pivot syntax been implemented in Teradata 14.10+ (15.xx)?

Tags: pivot, teradata

Looks like the TD14.10 release brought us the ability to unpivot using the TD_UNPIVOT function, which was neat.
What about the PIVOT syntax, did it get implemented?

So far, through the older releases, we've been using the whole

```
max(case when "year"='2010' then pivot_col end) "2010", ...
```

construction to mimic the pivots, but this requires the prior (static) knowledge of value/column list. Also, it appears to be expensive in terms of perf overhead (slower queries, that is)

Haven't seen any references so far in the newer versions of TD.

Comment: Afaik it's scgeduled for the next release, TD16, but you probably still need to know about the value list, so it's just simplified version of the MAX/CASE (e.g. in SQL Server it's translated to this).